# Converting SQL Loader from Windows bat to Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, batch-file, sql-loader

I have a SQL Loader bat file that works in Windows. I am trying to convert it to a Linux script but running into all sorts of errors.

Here is the Windows bat:

```
sqlldr user@database/password ^
       control='.\Control\control_file.ctl' ^
       data   ='.\Data\data_file.txt' ^
       log    ='.\Log\log_file.log' ^
       bad    ='.\Bad\bad_file.bad'
```

Here is the Linux version I created:

```
sqlldr userid = user@database/password
       control ='../ctl/control_file.ctl'
       data   ='../data/data_file.txt'
       log    ='../log/log_file.log'
       bad    ='../bad/bad_file.bad'
```

Looks like my format is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To continue lines in a shell script you need to have `\\` at the end (akin to having `^` at the end for the batch script. Alternatively just put it all on one line. Also the spaces in those arguments probably isn't going to work in the shell so remove them (e.g. `data='../data/data_file.txt'`)

Comment: Thanks so much @EtanReisner. I was able to get it to work with your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue lines in a shell script you need to have ` at the end (akin to having ^` at the end for the batch script.

Alternatively just put it all on one line.

Also the spaces in those arguments probably isn't going to work in the shell so remove them (e.g. data='../data/data_file.txt')